# pass data from controller to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewdata

I know there are many ways to do it. But i want to pass  cerq  text to view. but i want to see just cerq in div. That is i do not want to see div tags instead i want browser to interpret it.

this is my function in controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {  
        ViewData["cerq"] = "<div>Baha</div>";  
        return View();
    }
```

and this is my view part

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "abc";
    Layout = "~/Views/Common/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>MenuDene  - @ViewData["cerq"] - </h2>
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

in view i wrote

```
@Html.Raw(ViewData["cerq"])
```

and it solves.